# Any way to get a users hardware MAC address via PHP?

Tags: php

I'm thinking this is a no, as I don't see it in the $_SERVER var, but is there any way to see the MAC address of a user who views a page on a site?

A client would like to log both the IP and MAC addresses, but I'm not sure how I would go about getting the MAC.

Comment: MAC address isn't sent to the interwebs. So no. No way. Only the local network knows the client's MAC addr.

Comment: The MAC address is not one of the fields in an HTTP request, so no, it would not be possible.

Comment: Not without creating a form that says "enter your MAC address here"

Comment: Thanks guys, pretty much what I thought. Also google, and the stack overflow search didn't provide me with a link the older question, so sorry for posting a duplicate.

Comment: A MAC address is private hardware information that clients are not entitled to anyway, so it is good that it is not available. It would be like an undeletable cookie.